# My 1TB WD Caviar Green HDD is making a short high-pitched sound every half second

Tags: hard-drive

My 1TB WD Caviar Green HDD is making a short (about 0.1 second) high-pitched sound every half second. It is barely audible, but is enough to drive me crazy. I’ve noticed that the sound is synchronized with the HDD Activity LED on the front of my case. I am running Windows 8.1 on a custom built computer.

The hard drive has given me no problems at all except for this sound; it runs great, has had no errors, and has always worked. The hard drive has been in my computer for well over a year by now, with not much downtime.

I’m unsure where to begin diagnosing the problem since I can't find anyone else with the same problem, and none of the common hard drive noises I've read about have mentioned this.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Is it normal? Should I be worried?
I can provide any details necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it sound like screeching metal?

If so, likely the ball bearings in the disk spinning mechanism has lost some lubrication; the resulting friction makes those noises, just like any other daily mechanical device you'd use that grinds/rolls surface to surface.

Obviously you cannot pry open the mechanism to spray some WD-40 on it. Best case is the friction is insignificant and wouldn't damage the bearings. Worst case is over the long run wear and tear would accumulate and result in spinning faults.

Best to contact Western Digital tech support if they can replace the disk.

Comment: It does, in fact, sound like screeching metal. This seems to be the most likely cause. I'll do as you said and contact Western Digital, thank you so much!

Comment: A wild suggestion: try changing the orientation of the drive. The forces on the ball bearings will change and this may make the noise go away. This fixed my noise issue with a fan last week. It might even redistribute the lubricant (this trick has been used in astronomy satellites/robots).

Comment: Use WD DLG to test the HDD health. You can download it here : http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=mrR10t . After you have the results you can contact our support on the numbers found here: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=Epjp5l

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the tip! I never thought of it that way. The reviews online seemed pretty good.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD I started an extended test today, and it has been running for over 7 hours and is stuck on sector 1787973887 of 1953525167. It won't cancel, and I am unable to access the drive anymore. :( Not sure whether I should restart or wait. I guess I'll just wait.

Comment: @Mitch Given that the WD DLG seems to be hanging on a specific disk location, it could still be bad sectors. Get yourself a copy of [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm). It's $89 US but has a money back guarantee, and it does wonders on bad sectors (I doubt that WD DLG does bad sector *recovery*). It may also need some time, though...

Comment: @JanDoggen I'll check SpinRite out, thanks! I left the program running for a full 24 hours and it never moved. I had to force restart the computer, since it hung while normally restarting. The drive is working again now, but I'm in the process of backing it up because I don't trust it anymore :P